# In Hybris what the difference between ant deploy and ant all

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone please tell the difference in hybris of ant deploy and ant all. 
According to me ant deploy will deploy code without any re-compliation.
It is said it takes only changes in configurations.
I dont see this making any sense as property and .xml files dont need any ant all.
So does ant deploy build items.xml and beans files?

Answer (score 4):

You call `ant deploy` when you use `ant server`. This command is used to update the configuration done for tomcat/tcserver in `/hybris/config` to `/hybris/bin/platform`. It restarts the server if it's already started.

`ant all` executes `ant build` and `ant server`. `ant build` is in charge of compilation of java code, hybris beans, and items.

Answer (score 1):

No, ant deploy doesn't build the items.xml or beans.xml.
The ant task description says

```
"Deploys platform to bundled server. Will copy files of config/tomcat or config/tcServer to config folder of configured bundled server."
```

It allows you to use some hooks in your extension's buildcallbacks.xml if your extensions have specific deploy requirements.

But in my almost five years of hybris experience though I have never had the need to run the ant deploy task.
(In fact, until I read this question I wasn't even aware of it as a task).
The day-to-day task (and usually also in actual deployments for go-live etc) "ant all" is what is being used.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My  Experience  Has  Been  Slightly Different From Sebastian.

Ant   Deploy  Used  for  Faster  Deployment   Without   Re  -  Compiling  Platform.

Comment: So you keep deploying without making any changes ?